# How to toggle HTML radio button with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a radio button that is checked by default. What I am trying to accomplish is just to toggle it on/off with a click and simple logic but I do not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my HTML:

```
   <input type="radio" id="member" name="member" value="member" checked>
   <label for="member" >Member Reported</label>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
$('#member').click((e) => {
    console.log('click')
    if($('#member').is(':checked')) { 
        $('#member').prop('checked',false)
    }
})
```

This works great, but I noticed that it's not changing the DOM once clicked, and furthermore, when I try to add the prop to true (like below), it's not checking back on the GUI.

Here's the DOM:

[image]

```
$('#member').click((e) => {
    console.log('click')
    if($('#member').is(':checked')) { 
        $('#member').prop('checked',false)
    } else if (!$('#member').is(':checked')) {
        $('#member').prop('checked',true)
    }
})
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the checked prop than setting it to false. $('# member').removeAttr('checked')

Comment: A radio button is not a check box. You can't toggle it. You know that already thats why you are doing this workaround. You can reset it but you need to reset the group, which is identified by the name. You have used id instead and Id should be unique. If you are using the same id for all the options, that wont work. Basically radio buttons can't have ids. Point is if you using just one option use checkbox instead of radio button. If its going to be more than one that we are seeing reset using name.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Is this what you are willing?

```js
$('#member + label').click((e) => {
    console.log($('#member')[0].checked);
    if($('#member')[0].checked) { 
        $('#member')[0].checked = false;
    } else{
        $('#member')[0].checked = true;
    }
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="member" name="member" value="member" checked >
   <label for="" >Member Reported</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long `checked` exist in element, it will stay checked. You will have to remove it via jquery to make it work.

You can check functioning here.

```html
<input type="radio" checked>
<br>
<input type="radio" checked="true">
<br>
<input type="radio" checked="false">
<br>
<input type="radio">
```

Comment: @Spectric thanks for pointing that out, someone posted functioning code so I decided to remove it altogether

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the way it should be.

```js
$('.radios').click((e) => {
  $('.radios').each(function (i) {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="member" class="radios" name="member" value="member" >
<label for="member" >Member Reported</label><br/>
<input type="radio" id="member2" class="radios" name="member" value="member" >
<label for="member2" >Member Reported2</label><br/>
<input type="radio" id="member3" class="radios" name="member" value="member" checked>
<label for="member3" >Member Reported3</label><br/>
```